# How to use NSBundle with xib file and Base Internationalization

Tags: ios, internationalization, bundle, xib, radix

I'm trying to localize my app (say English and France) and allow user to select language right in my app.

So I must use NSBundle to actively select the language folder, as described in this [Advance Localization in ios apps](http://learning-ios.blogspot.com/2011/04/advance-localization-in-ios-apps.html)

The main bundle (`[NSBundle mainBundle]`) seems to select the preferred language in the Settings (`[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]`), so I must select the bundle myself

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fr" ofType:@"lproj"];

NSBundle *frBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
```

It works fine for Localizable.strings because those strings files are added to every .lproj folder.

But when I localize xib file, it does not work. Because **only the MyViewController.xib file gets added to Base.lproj**, while the MyViewController.strings files are added to every .lproj folder

So this code

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:frBundle]
```

will fire "Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle (loaded)' with name 'MyViewController"

So how deal with this ?